# Proof of estimation error increases (logarithmically) with hypothesis class size for a finite hypothesis class

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

In section 5.2 error decomposition (p.404) from the book "Shai et al., *Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Applications*", the authors wrote:

> As we have shown, for a finite hypothesis class, $\epsilon_{est}$ increases (logarithmically) with $|\mathcal{H}|$ and decreases with $m$.

Where $\epsilon_{est}$ denotes the estimation error, $\mathcal{H}$ is the hypothesis class and $m$ is the size of the training set.

But I couldn't find any proof of this statement anywhere in the book, so I've tried to construct one. I can deduce the second part of the statement, i.e the estimation error decreases with $m$ but  I'm still struggling with the first part to show that the error increases logarithmically with $|\mathcal{H}|$.

Answer (score 1):

Using notations from the book, we have that $\epsilon_{est} := L_D(h_S) - \min_{h\in\mathcal H} L_D(h)$, but since $h_S$ is fixed, we can write
$$\begin{align}\epsilon_{est} :&= L_D(h_S) - \min_{h\in\mathcal H} L_D(h) \\
&=\max_{h\in\mathcal H}\left[ L_D(h_S) -  L_D(h)\right]\\
&= \max_{h\in\mathcal H}\left[ L_D(h_S) - L_S(h_S) + L_S(h_S) -  L_D(h)\right]\\
&\le |L_D(h_S) - L_S(h_S)| + \max_{h\in\mathcal H}\left| L_S(h_S) -  L_D(h)\right| \\
&\le 2\max_{h\in\mathcal H}\left| L_S(h) -  L_D(h)\right|\tag1\label{eps} \end{align} $$

And in Section 4.2 of the book, it is shown as a corollary of Hoeffding's inequality that, for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$\mathbb P\left(\max_{h\in\mathcal H}\left| L_S(h) -  L_D(h)\right|>\epsilon\right)\le 2|\mathcal H|\exp(-2m\epsilon^2) $$

So if we let $\delta :=2|\mathcal H|\exp(-2m\epsilon^2)$, we have that with probability at least $1-\delta$,
$$\left| L_S(h) -  L_D(h)\right|\le\epsilon\implies L_D(h)\le L_S(h)+\epsilon $$
And the above holds for all $h\in\mathcal H$. Now, expressing $\epsilon$ in terms of $\delta, |\mathcal H|$ and $m$, we get that for all $h\in\mathcal H$,
$$L_D(h) - L_S(h)\le \sqrt{\frac{\ln|\mathcal{H}| + \ln{\frac{2}{\delta}}}{2m}} $$

With probability greater than $1-\delta$. Finally, by inequality \eqref{eps} we've shown above, it follows that with probability greater than $1-\delta$,
$$\epsilon_{est} \le 2 \sqrt{\frac{\ln|\mathcal{H}| + \ln{\frac{2}{\delta}}}{2m}}. $$
Which we can see (assuming the bound is tight), increases with $|\mathcal H|$ as $2\sqrt{\ln|\mathcal H|} $ and decreases with $m$ as $\sqrt{2/m} $.

Comment: everything is clear to me except the last assumption, it's not convincing isn't it?

Comment: And also we couldn't substitute $\epsilon=log(|\mathcal{H}|/\delta)/m$ or $\epsilon\ge log(|\mathcal{H}|/\delta)/m$ into the equality right?

Comment: @TranKhanh well, you don't need that assumption to show that the error decreases like $1/\sqrt m$, but you need it to show the $\sqrt{\ln|\mathcal H|}$-increase. They don't show that the assumption actually holds in the book (or in any other place I've checked), but 1) I think it is meant as an heuristic rather than a formal argument (a rough estimate of how quickly the error can increase with $|\mathcal H|$ in the worst case scenario, and 2) my gut feeling is that the bound is indeed tight, i.e. it should be possible to cook up a distribution for which the estimation error is within...

Comment: ... a constant factor of $\sqrt{\frac{\ln|\mathcal{H}| + \ln{\frac{2}{\delta}}}{2m}}$. Also for your second question, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. We already fixed $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon, |\mathcal{H}|$ and $m$, so the expression of $\epsilon$ is given by the definition of $\delta$, at this point we can't change it. And the choice of $\delta$ itself follows from the bound given by Hoeffding's inequality, so there isn't really much room/justification to change it at this point.

Comment: I think the same as what you've put in your very first comment above, since $L_D(h_S)$ depends on $h_S$ and $h_S$, in turn, depends on chance of sampling, I believe authors need to employ some sort of probability to the argument (it's not 100% true for all choices of the training sample $S^{m}$). There're indeed tight bounds (both upper and lower) in the next chapter for finite VC-dim (including hypothesis classes of infinite sizes).